# Stringifying spaces with reg expressions

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a sentence like this :

```
"Hey  what is up
```

Note the two spaces after `Hey`.

I am using the following regex to split this sentence into array of strings:

```
string[] tokensArr = Regex.Split(data, "( )");
```

Now, for me important to have each space as a separate string too. But what happens is that if I insert more than one space in row, the split returns 3 space strings and not 2 (with 3 spaces in row it returns 5, etc). The extra one in the debugger looks like this `""` and not `" "`. Why is it inserted? How can I get rid of it remaining only with the spaces I actually inserted?

To make it clear again:
My intention is not filter double/triple spaces.But to get rid of additional space I get when splitting them.Just try it out:

Type some text with double space between 2 words.Run it through the method above and you see the split returns instead of 2 items of spaces 3.

Comment: something like `"\s+"` comes to mind, i.e. one or more whitespace charachters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you had commas instead of spaces

```
Hey,,what,is,up
```

This looks like CSV input with fields

```
"Hey"
""
"what"
"is"
"up"
```

doesn't it? So if you split on `,`, you'd expect to get an empty string. If you split on `(,)`, to capture the delimiters as well, you'd still expect that to be there. The same applies if you do that with spaces.

So the only option you have is go over your array in the end, and remove empty strings, I guess.

```
string[] tokensArr = Regex.Split(data, "( )").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
```

This will give you

```
"Hey", " ", " ", "what", " ", "is", " ", "up"
```

If instead, you want to to have only one string, that contains both spaces, don't split on single spaces, but on one-or-more spaces:

```
string[] tokensArr = Regex.Split(data, "([ ]+)")
```

The square brackets are optional, but aid readability. This will give you

```
"Hey", "  ", "what", " ", "is", " ", "up"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering why an additional item is being added when you have 2 spaces, think about what it's trying to do.  It takes each string between each space.  If you have 2 spaces, then the string between them is empty, but it's certainly still a valid string.

Another way to think of it is, if you are splitting a word on a letter, say 'a', then there wouldn't be any 'a' in any of the values returned from the split. If you split on spaces, there would be no spaces in the values returned.